# Scenario for offline file access

Tags: ios

Scenario:

After downloading  the file from Server, we have to store it in device’s local and fetch from their for later use.

This is for reducing unnecessary hits to DB to get the same file again and again. And accessing file offline too (when user don’t have internet access, he can able to fetch file from local).

How can we implement the above scenario in iOS devices for videos?

Answer (score 0):

*This solution will work only if files have unique names.*
You can create a local db in which you have to store all file names which you have already downloaded from server.
Whenever user want to see a file you have to first check thes local db.
If file is already downloaded you can take the file and play it.

Comment: I want to implement this for a hybrid app..what exactly the code will be?

Comment: Explain your Scenario.